# Getting 405-Method not allowed in self hosted web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, jsonp, http-status-code-405

I created a `WCF self hosted` web service. Here are my `serviceContract and OperationContract` in `Instace` class:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISwiperWS
{   

[OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/getstatus?callback={Callback}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
String getStatus(String Callback);
}
```

TestWS.cs

```
public String getStatus()
{
  return "true"
}
```

I am accessing the endpoint of this web service from `JsonP` written in `GWT`

```
String url = "https://somedomain.com:8083/getstatus";
JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
jsonp.setTimeout(600);
jsonp.setCallbackParam("callback");
jsonp.send(url);
```

I create a setup project and installed it on different-different machine. Whenever i am making a request to web service endpoints from `JsonP` It is showing an strange behavior. In some machine i am getting an expected response where as in some other machine it continuously showing an error i.e. `405-method are not allowed`.

I searched it for and make change according to them but nothing works for me. Please suggest me a solutoin

Answer (score 1):

May be: I believe it had something to do with your jquery ajax call using jsonp. If you are going to change it to just json the post will work..

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation